# For Google Workspace, I am trying to get the a list together of all the users' other contacts in my domain

Tags: python, google-people-api

I want to get the "Other Contacts" List for all users in my domain. I can currently get my user's "Other Contacts" list with the following:

```
results = service.otherContacts().list(
        readMask="names,emailAddresses").execute()
```

But is there a way to get other users' lists as well?

Comment: I do not think so, because you're requesting Google by your own API credentials only.

Comment: Correct, but as a domain admin, I have rights to access all that information as an admin. I just want a convenient way to pull this specific data out.

Answer (score 0):

If you already can get your 'Other contacts' with that code, all you need to implement is `user impersonation` in your code, something like:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import credentials, service_account
 
SCOPES = [Your Scopes list]

# Service Account Credentials to be used. How to create at https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#service-account
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'yourServiceAccountCredentials.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes= SCOPES)
delegated_creds = credentials.with_subject('UserToBeImpersonated@yourdomain.com')
```

And since you are using Google Workspace after you create your [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#service-account) and generate the JSON file key you will need to configure [Domain Wide Delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106) using the client ID of your Service Account plus the scopes you will use.